# Auto upgradation of docker memory

Tags: docker, containers

I want to upgrade docker memory dynamically for e.g. I have assign 1gb of memory to the container but if the memory reaches near 1gb it should dynamically allot another 512mb or 1gb or something so how can i achieve while create or running docker.

Comment: Do you have an existing `docker run` command or something else, that applies a memory limit or reservation?  By default every container can use all available system memory.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze , sorry for late reply. I am running the container with following command -  **docker container run -d  -p 10001:6379  -m 1g -h 'Container Name' 'Image Name' **